# Can you tell docker what network interface to use?

Tags: docker, containers

I would like to know how can you set up Docker to use a specific network interface.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about setting a default gateway, you would add the `--default-gateway=IP_ADDRESS` to the docker daemon run command.

It's all in [here](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/)

Comment: Do be more specific. I have 2 WiFi adapters, and I want to have different containers to each make use of them. I am not sure if that will help me.